# Regular Expresions JS

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

Can someone tell me why the code does not work without \D here? I need to use lookaheads in the pwRegex to match passwords that are greater than 5 characters long, do not begin with numbers, and have two consecutive digits.

```
let sampleWord = "abc123";
var pwRegex =  /^\D(?=\w{5})(?=\w*\d{2})/;
let result = pwRegex.test(sampleWord);    //true
```

Thanks!

Comment: `do not begin with numbers`, `^\D` matches any char but not of a number. You could also use `[^\d]` instead of `\D`

Comment: and why it's used \w* if already has \w?

Comment: `have two consecutive digits` - `(?=\w*\d{2})` ensures that the string must contain two consecutive digits irrespective of it's position. If we remove `\w*` from the lookahead then it means that the first not digit char must be followed by two consecutive digits.

Comment: why can't i accept your answer? are you the same Raj as programmerRaj?

Comment: no, you can't accept comments. Just accept another Raj's answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regex, `\d` matches any digit character, and `\D` matches any character that is *not* a digit character. `^` means the start of the string, so `^\D` means the starting character is not a digit.

> ... do not begin with numbers,...

The `\D` is for it to not begin with numbers.